# Android SQLite - not able to create Table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is an extraction of my MainActivity in which i want to create a database table

```
public class GameDrive extends Activity {


DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_drive);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database  = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

.
.
.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABSE_NAME = "database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tripdata";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_TYP = "typ";
private static final String COLUMN_VALUE = "value";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;




public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("Database","Constructor called");

}


//database is created for first time. creation of table and initial data inside done here
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("Database","onCreate called");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COLUMN_TYP+" VARCHAR(255),"+COLUMN_VALUE+" VARCHAR(255));" );

    Log.d("Database","onCreate called succesfuly");

}

//drop tables, add tables etc.
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME");
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Why is the Log.d("Database","onCreate called") never reached? After starting the app just the       Log.d("Database","Constructor called") statement is reached.

Thank you!

Comment: clear your data and test again

Comment: onCreate will be called upon first installation, or on upgrading database version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the table is already there. So onDreate will not get executed again. Try installing SQLite Viewer to better visualize your DB.
I also cannot see method getWritableDatabase() in your DatabaseHelper. Please also check on this.

Another thing you could try is modify your create table command into create table if not exists.